# Windows Phone 7, Conditional Rectangle fIll to new ImageSource possible?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

So I have a seemingly simple question:

How do I go about coding an "if rectangle.fill is X, change fill to this specific image" in C#? Here is my rectangle in XAML:

```
<Rectangle Height="auto" Width="auto" x:Name="Honey" ManipulationStarted="Honey_Started">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image100.jpg" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
```

That was simple, but how would the code behind look? The following example is obviously wrong, but am just including it to hopefully show what I wish to accomplish.

```
private void Honey_Started(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Honey.Fill == image100.jpg)
        {
            Honey.Fill = 900image.jpg;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking the filename of the `Fill`, you could change the Rectangle's `Tag` property (or create your own `UserControl`). Then, for example, you could do this:

```
<Rectangle Height="auto" Width="auto" x:Name="Honey" ManipulationStarted="Honey_Started" Tag="image1">
       <Rectangle.Fill>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="image100.jpg" />
       </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

I've added `Tag="image1"` as an attribute in your `Rectangle`. You can then access this in the codebehind and check.

```
private void Honey_Started(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Honey.Tag.ToString() == "image1")
        {
            ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
            BitmapImage bImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("900image.jpg",UriKind.Relative));
            ib.ImageSource = bImage;
            Honey.Tag = "900image.jpg";
            Honey.Fill = ib;
        }
    }
```

There are other methods as well. All I've done in the `Honey_Started` event is create a new `ImageBrush` in code, assigned it an image (`900image.jpg`) and then set that `ImageBrush` to be the `Fill` value for the rectangle.

An alternative method could be two store the two `ImageBrushes` as a class level variable and use them to compare the value.

```
BitmapImage biImage100 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Jar/image100.jpg",UriKind.Relative));
ImageBrush ibImage100 = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = biImage100 };
ImageBrush ib900image = new ImageBrush() { /*assign the 900image.jpg image*/ };

     private void Honey_Started(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
     {

           if (Honey.Fill == ibImage100)
           {
                Honey.Fill = ib900image;
           }
     }
```

Comment: Hi KeyboardP. The thing is is that this approach recognizes the Rectangle, but not the picture belonging to the rectangle. it's the images I wish to compare.

Comment: Hi Ryan. I forgot to update the `Honey` tag (I've added it in the code). When you make a change, you can update the rectangle's `Tag` property so it'll return the value you need. The reason you can't compare using `Honey.Fill == image100.jpg` is because `Fill` returns a `Brush` type, not the name of the image.

Comment: @Ryan - I've added an alternative method which would keep a class level copy of the Brush. You can then compare the brushes as shown.

Comment: I really appreciate your helping me. One final question (and extremely sorry for the hand holding here, but I'm seriously just learning this on the fly) is how you "assign the image100.jpg image" and such. Do you mean if the image was located in /Jar/image100.jpg, that I should write that in there?

Comment: @Ryan - No problem, we all learn sometime :). I've updated the code to show how to load `image100`. You can do the same thing for `900image`.